# Cannot resolve the name 'repository:repository' to a(n) 'type definition' component.

Tags: xml, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am getting this error while trying to integrate Spring Data. The full stack trace is

```
nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd; lineNumber: 18; columnNumber: 48; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'repository:repository' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
```

The XML file is

```
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">
    <repositories base-package="com.interviewedonline.poc.repositories" />
```

Comment: Did you find solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with the XSD file.

I've changed my Spring data Data Commons 1.4 to Spring Data Commons 1.3.2 and everything works perfectly fine now...

Answer (score 1):

You need to define [Spring Data JPA XML namespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.namespace) first:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.interviewedonline.poc.repositories" />

</beans>
```

Or if you want to use default XML namespace as in your example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <repositories base-package="com.interviewedonline.poc.repositories" />

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: No luck. I have tried both the options. Still getting the same exception. Not sure is there any jar conflict. I am using 3.1.2 version of spring.

Comment: @AnanthDuari: Do you have `spring-data-jpa*.jar` on your CLASSPATH? `spring*.jar` is not enough.

Comment: yes, I have spring-data-jpa-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, spring-data-rest-core-1.0.0.RC3.jar, spring-data-rest-repository-1.0.0.RC3.jar and spring-data-rest-webmvc-1.0.0.RC3.jar. Still getting the error.

Comment: have tried with different versions of XSD. Still the same problem. Even though I can see repository:repository there. Tried with http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd

Comment: I am getting exactly the same issue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246106/how-to-integrate-spring-data-jpa-and-spring-data-solr/13264352#13264352

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Adding `spring-data-commons-core` seemed to fix it for me.

Comment: Could you please share your spring(and spring-data spring-data-solr) version?

Comment: I'm using spring 3.1.1, spring-data-jpa-1.1.0, and spring-data-commons-core-1.3.0.

Comment: After changing the version of spring-data-commons-core from 1.4.0 to 1.3.0， I got java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtension

Comment: @Tom have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

I added this jar **spring-data-commons-core-1.2.1.RELEASE**

In Pom.xml added the below entry

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

In the jpa configurator file added the below entry under xsi:schemaLocation
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this error updating the dependencies of an old project. The problem I had was that this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

has been renamed and now the correct one is

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

As I had declared **spring-data-commons-core** and **spring-data-commons** was a transitive dependency of data-mongodb, I ended up with both jars and the classloader was using spring-data-commons-core that is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In some Spring .jar files,you can find META-INF folder.You'll find spring.handlers and spring.schemas in that folder. spring-data-commons-*.jar do have. If you use Maven, you should create META-INF folder under src/main/resources and append the content of spring.handlers,spring.schemas in the spring-data-commons-*.jar to your spring.handlers,spring.schemas.

Have a good luck!